# Problem with patch SUPEE-10888 on Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-10888

Problem with patch PATCH_SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.9.0.1_v1-2018-09-19-03-00-53.sh on Magento 1.9.0.1, with all previous patches installed:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 623 (offset -19 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 57.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 80 (offset -12 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 115 with fuzz 2 (offset -12 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 139 with fuzz 1 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 161 (offset -21 lines).
1 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1029 (offset -1 lines).
```

Does anyone recognize this error message?

**Solution**
Installing SUPEE-10752 was the solution.

Comment: Check you have applied all security patch 10415,10752

Comment: It looks like we missed SUPEE-10752. Will do that patch first and come back here. Thank you Rama!

Comment: Installing SUPEE-10752 was the solution.

Comment: Thanks. i will date ans here please accept it. it will helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missed the security patch 10415,10752. Please apply and then apply supee 10888 patch.